# Linking GSL static library on Ubuntu with Visaul Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, c++11, ubuntu-18.04, gsl

I installed GSL Scientific Library on Ubuntu 18.04 from the distro package:

```
sudo apt-get install libgsl-dev
```

The libraries libgsl.a and libgslcblas.a are installed in:

```
/usr/lin/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

directory.

The VS cross platform project references the path in "Additional Library Directories". The libraries binaries names, libgsl and libgslcblas, are set in Library Dependencies. The VS project is built for x64 platform.

During compilation I get the following errors:

```
1>/usr/bin/ld : error : cannot find -llibgsl
1>/usr/bin/ld : error : cannot find -llibgslcblas
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

when referencing libraries in project properties, don't use the lib prefix:
gsl;gslcblas